# How to make custon data source in QlikView?

Tags: c++, scripting, qlikview

I have just started to develop in QlikView so I'm completely a newbie.

The problem that I have is that I need to create a c++ dll that can be used as a custom data source for QlikView, I already created the dll and QlikView can see it, but I don't know how should I do to make my data available to QlikView.

The data that I want to use is obtained as a request from the server, and the code is inside the c++ dll.

I had some examples that my boss got from QlikView tech department, they are SalesForce example and EbayDll example but they are kind of confusing, so I was wondering if you can point me to another example that may be easier to follow, or if you can give me some pointers that help me accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just if someone is interested, I posted the same question in the QlikView Forum and the answer that I got was

> "Get the version 9 SDK. It includes doc and a sample for a Custom Data Source. The SDK is available on a QV Server installation. If not already installed, I believe you can download the QVS9 and just install the SDK portion on your workstation."

The example contained in the SDK actually help me out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In QlikView 10 you can now use (the easier approach) of using the QVX API!

Regards
Stefan